# Best practice to validate null and set Data

Tags: java

I have this piece of code , checking the null condition and setting the data as shown below

```
public EmployeeVO  buildEmpVO(EmpInfo empInfo) {
        EmployeeVO empVo = new EmployeeVO();
        if(empInfo.getEmpObject()!=null)
        {
        empVo.setLength(empInfo.getEmpObject().getMonths());
        }
        else
        {
            empVo.setLength(0);
        }
        
        return empVo;
    }
```

This code works , but is there anyway , the code can be improved .

Comment: `empVo.setLength(empInfo.getEmpObject().getMonths() != null ? empInfo.getEmpObject().getMonths() : 0);` Perhaps use a [Ternary Operator](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/ternary-operator.html). To be honest, I think what you have is easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `Optional` for that task (assuming `getMonths()` returns `int`):

```
int length = Optional.ofNullable(empInfo.getEmpObject())
                        .map(empObj -> empObj.getMonths()).orElse(0);
empVo.setLength(length);
```

Or, if you prefer one line:

```
empVo.setLength(Optional.ofNullable(empInfo.getEmpObject()).map(empObj -> empObj.getMonths()).orElse(0));
```

Comment: Please, the user that down voted can add a comment to explain why. It's very useful learning from my mistakes.

Comment: It's probably because you're answering an off-topic question. This question is primarily opinion based and too broad. You're better off [avoiding such questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That could be a reason to down vote a question, not an answer. On the other hand, who says is off-topic? When I answered was an open question.

Comment: Questions always start open until they are closed by the community. That doesn't mean that while they are open, that they are not off-topic. They're just not closed yet. The help center says which kinds of questions are on- and off-topic. From there: "_[Questions which are too broad, unclear, incomplete or primarily opinion-based may be closed by the community until they are improved.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_"

Comment: Again, that could be a reason to down vote a question, not an answer. And, until is closed, is still your opinion. I'm not saying you are wrong but, if it were an exact science to decide what is off-topic, a bot would do the job, not users voting.

Answer (score 0):

Well one way to make the code a bit easier to read would be to define a variable to hold the employee object:

```
public EmployeeVO buildEmpVO(EmpInfo empInfo) {
    EmployeeVO empVo = new EmployeeVO();
    EmpObject eo = empInfo.getEmpObject();

    if (eo != null) {
        empVo.setLength(eo.getMonths());
    }
    else {
        empVo.setLength(0);
    }
    
    return empVo;
}
```

Note that I did not add a check on the input `empInfo` to the method itself.  You might want to also check for this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 8, then you can shorten the code using Optional.

```
  public EmployeeVO  buildEmpVO(EmpInfo empInfo) {
    EmployeeVO empVo = new EmployeeVO();
    Optional.of(empInfo.getEmpObject()).ifPresentOrElse(empObject -> empVo.setLength(empObject.getMonths()),
        () -> empVo.setLength(0));
    return empVo;
  }
```

But this is equally good as the approach you are using.